# Form submits but no data present in console

Tags: javascript, html, forms, ecmascript-6, ecma

I am trying to make my first form using HTML and JS(vanilla). When I submit the form the console shows the form coming in but as I check through it, there appears to be none of the data i entered into the fields.

I have read through a number of the forum posts on here and other forum sites but most of the are using Jquery, React, or some other framework, I am super new to this and forms are already hard enough.

```js
window.onload = () => {

    formID.addEventListener("submit" , (e) =>
    {
        console.log("form event listener activated");
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("default prevented");
        console.log("formID: " , e);
        myModule.addToTable(e);

    });
}

function addToTable(e) {
  console.log("e " , e);
  console.log("e target " , e.target);
  console.log("e target.value " , e.target.value);

  console.log("this is a test, line 80 client.js");
}
```

```html
<form id="FormID" class="FormClass" method='POST' action="#">
       <input class="inputClass" type="text" name='Name' placeholder="Name" value=""/> <br/><br/>
       <input class="inputClass" type="text" name='Model-Num' placeholder="Model Number" value=""/> <br/><br/>
       <input class="inputClass" type="text" name='Current-Stock' placeholder="Current Stock Amount" value=""/> <br/><br/>
       <input class="inputClass" type="text" name='Target-Stock' placeholder="Target Stock" value=""/> <br/><br/>
       <input class="inputClass" type="text" name='Reorder-Amount' placeholder="Reorder Amount" value=""/> <br/> <br/>


        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/> 
</form>
```

Result
 under the target area i see

```
textContent: "↵                ↵                ↵                ↵
```

or

```
"↵↵↵↵↵↵↵↵↵↵"
```

I am of course wanting to get the actual values for my fields that were entered in the text box. Any help is absolutely appreciated.

Remember, I am super new, I do not understand a lot fo the backend DOM but I am trying to learn it.

Comment: The elements are in the [`elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements) collection property on the form object, in your example `e.target.elements`, or `formID.elements`

Comment: Please don't to `formID.elements`, referencing elements by their ID was never a good idea and is only maintained for historic reasons. Use `forms.FormID.elements`. Within the listener, the form is referenced by *this* so `this.elements`.

Comment: Using a slash for self–closing elements (e.g. `/>`) is unnecessary junk in the page, just don't do it.

Comment: good to know, ty @RobG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it is not working is because you are using `formID` without even initializing the element to it. Try this instead

```
document.getElementById("FormID").addEventListener("submit" , (e) => { 
     //your code here
});
```

I also noticed that you use `myModule` in calling `addToTable(e)` which will cause error(based on that snippet) because `myModule` is undefined. Just call `addToTable(e)` directly. Check the working version of your code below

```js
window.onload = () => {

    document.getElementById("FormID").addEventListener("submit" , (e) =>
    {
        console.log("form event listener activated");
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("default prevented");
        console.log("formID: " , e);
        addToTable(e);

    });
}

function addToTable(e) {
  console.log("e " , e);
  console.log("e target " , e.target);
  console.log("e target.value " , e.target.value);

  console.log("this is a test, line 80 client.js");
}
```

```html
<form id="FormID" class="FormClass" method='POST' action="#">
       <input class="inputClass" type="text" name='Name' placeholder="Name" value=""/> <br/><br/>
       <input class="inputClass" type="text" name='Model-Num' placeholder="Model Number" value=""/> <br/><br/>
       <input class="inputClass" type="text" name='Current-Stock' placeholder="Current Stock Amount" value=""/> <br/><br/>
       <input class="inputClass" type="text" name='Target-Stock' placeholder="Target Stock" value=""/> <br/><br/>
       <input class="inputClass" type="text" name='Reorder-Amount' placeholder="Reorder Amount" value=""/> <br/> <br/>


        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/> 
</form>
```

Comment: oh sorry, I did have myModule and the formID declared above the window.onload function.

I tried you solution but I cannot find the inputted values there either. I think I am missing something here but I am not sure what exactly.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, got busy on work. No problem. Glad that it helped :)